# displaying the output on chart.js using Django and HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, chart.js

I have data that i need to pass to HTML file to ctreate chart using chart.js

heres the view.py
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
the commented code is to print only the data in text form on the HTML file

heres the HTML file that i want to use on it the chart.js
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

can you give me an idea of how can I pass the data to work with chart.js do I need to conver it ? or can you suggest another way to visualize the data with stylish bar chart
the data in form of dict
heres sample of it {'values': [3, 1, 1], 'data_labels': [' data 1 ', ' data 2', ' data 3']}
..
if have any details questions tell me please
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crLZP.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlre5.png

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally data like that is served from a separate endpoint, so when your front-end needs chart data (in that model), it would make a `fetch` to get it from a separate URL on your site, eg. `yoursite.com/chartdata/5`.

However, if you have the data already on load, you can simply put it into a Javascript variable, by outputting it inside a `<script>` tag, eg.

```
 <script>
 const chartData = *outputHereAsJSON*;
 useYour(chartData);
 </script>
```

Comment: how can I pass the data from the views to the script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179386/displaying-the-render-response-on-the-javascript-on-html

can check my question there.

Comment: Yes, as @Reem Abdulrhman suggested in his link, you output your JSON data string (where I wrote `*ouputHereAsJSON*`) the same way you would output *any* string in Django ... by using the two curly brace templating syntax.  As far as Django is concerned, your HTML is just one big string, compiled from a template and data, and your JSON data is just a substring within it, the same as any other.